# A flea is jumping backwards and forwards along a line. The flea’s den is on the line. The jumps obey the following rules, where d is the distance:

Tags: combinatorics

A flea is jumping backwards and forwards along a line. The flea’s den is on the line. The
jumps obey the following rules, where $d$ is the distance of the flea from its den before a jump:

(i) If $d$<1, the flea will land $2d$ from the den;

(ii) If $d$≥ 1, the flea will land $1/d$ from the den.

(a) Show that the flea can never be more than distance 2 from the den after the first jump.

(b) From how many start positions could the flea have jumped exactly 5 times and landed a
distance 0.8 from the den?

(c) Are there any positions from which the flea can jump backwards and forwards between
just 2 positions in a cycle?

For part (a), I don't know how to prove it; I kind of just know that it won't because if $d$ is > 1, it will be a fraction less than one and then will keep doubling until it is more than 1 again, where the cycle repeats.  Would that just be the answer?

For part (b) and (c), would you just use trial and error or is there a more elegant way to solve it?

Any help would be appreciated.

Thank You!

Comment: Flea?  The  bass guitarist of *Red Hot Chilli Peppers?*

Comment: "the flea will land <some distance> from the den": but there are two such positions. Is the flea constrained to land always to the right (or always to the left) of the den? The answer to part (b) depends on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For part c, say your two positions are $d_1<1$ and $d_2>1$. Then $$d_2=2d_1\\d_1=1/d_2$$
Solving this system yields $$d_1=\frac1{\sqrt2}\\d_2=\sqrt 2$$
Similarly, you can have the negative values as well.

For part b, you need to solve it backwards. At the 4th jump, you are either at $d=0.4$ or $d=1/0.8=1.25$. For the first case, at the third jump you were either at $d=0.2$ or $d=1/0.4=2.5$. But you already proved in part a that you can't get to $2.5$. For the second case, where the distance at step 4 was $1.25$, the position at step 3 was $1.25/2$. And so on.

Comment: Thank you for your help.